how to setup Gitlab container registry, from self-hosted gitlab(community edition), will it work in http or https
I have enabled container registry option in gitlab configuration file, still I could not push images to gitlab.
Getting error as Retrying... layer already exists.
And, also having a confusion in gitlab container registry, where it will work in http or https.

tried modifying gitlab configuration file
also created a openssl certificate , added in gitlab configuration, but it causing issue in gitlab UI, as well as gitlab's UI port is getting auto-assigned to Prometheus, when checked for issues

